# Iterated Squaring Time Complexity

Tags: python, time-complexity

I have the following implementation of iterated squaring:

```
def power(a, b):
  result = 1
  while b > 0:
    if b % 2 == 1:
      result = mult(result, a)
    a = mult(a, a)
    b = b // 2
  return result
```

The `mult()` method multiplies 2 given numbers, when if one is of length of `x` bits and the other one is of length of `y` bits, the number of operations the multiplication will take is `x*y+(x+y)` operations, which I need to consider in the complexity analysis.

And I'm trying to find an `O()` notation bound of the number of arithemtic operations done as a function of `n` and `m` when a is n-bits long, and b is m-bits long. I need to take into consideration only the multiplication lines, and check for the worst case.

The worst case is when `b` is an m-bit number where all `m` binary digits are 1, and then I have `m` iterations of the loop where in each iteration the if condition is true.

What I dont know how to do is how  I should consider in my computation the fact that `a` grows for each iteration? How to I put it in some sort of finite sum with probably geometric progression that I can compute?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also, I know that multiplying 2 number of x bits and y bits will
>   result in x*y+(x+y) arithemtic operations.

That's not (in general) true. A processor will multiply two numbers in a defined number of cycles whether they are big or not. Unless you are dealing with huge numbers, you should consider, regarding asymptotic complexity (O), the  the multiplication as one operation, and the same applies for addition, division, ...

In your code, you have three of four operations per iteration of the loop (`if b % 2 == 1`, maybe `result = result*a`, `a = a*a`, `b = b // 2`). The complexity depends only on the number of iterations of the loop, that is: log2(b), because b is divided by two in each iteration.

For huge numbers, you have two operations that might have an impact on asymptotic complexity: `result = result*a` and `a = a*a`. Cpython uses the [Karatsuba multiplication](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c#L3269), which is O(n^log2(3)) if n is the number of digits if the numbers.

I will just elaborate on `a*a`. When you take the square of a number, you roughly multiply the number of digits by two. Consider the log2(b) loops: `a*a` take O(n^log2(3)) in the first iteration, O(2n^log2(3)) int the second, O(4n^log2(3)) int the second, ...,  O(bn)^log2(3)) in the last. The sum is O((b*log2(b)*n)^log2(3)), if I'm not wrong!

For `a*a`, , if you are bound to a O(x*y) mutlplication algorithm, then you have, for your log2(b) loops,

- O(n^2) for the first iteration;
- O((2n)^2) for the second iteration;
- O((4n)^2) for the third iteration;
- O((2^(k-1)*n)^2) for the k th iteration.

That's O(b^2 * n^2) = O(2^2m * n^2) I think (don't have the time to check now!).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately, for this task, I cannot consider the multiplication as one opertaion, and I do need to consider the number of arithmetic operations for my calculations. I've tried to formulate with the formula of number of arithemtic operations I have, but I cannot find how to formulate the line of `result=result*a` as a function of `i` (current iteration). Also, I didnt quite understand how you got the n^log2(3) computation for the first a*a, i got n^2+2n for the first one

Comment: @Jonathan it depends on the algorithm you are using for multiplication. See the link for Cpython.

Comment: oh sorry, didnt see that paragraph when i've read your answer. anyway, i am bound to a specific algorithm for multiplying 2 x,y-bits numbers with the solution for the number of iterations as i wrote

Comment: @Jonathan If you are bound to that algorithm, please edit your question and write it. E.g. `def mult(x, y): ...` and use `mult` in your code.

Comment: just saw your edit, your answer is the same as I got (my answer is down below) so I guess this is indeed the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the complexity of this algorithm is independent of a.

When reviewing the complexity, I think the number of loops is your main index for the highest complexity due to m.

Running through values of b, we can see following number if b > 0 computations as:

[image: Plot of number of n(b>0) computations for a give b value]

Interestingly, we see an increase in n loops for each multiple of 2 (i.e. 1,2,4,8,16,32,64).

Roughly speaking, I would say the complexity of this algorithm closely follows O(log2(n)).

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some analyzing, I think that the number of iterations of the `power` method will be sum on i (from 0 to m-1) of: `2^(2i-1)*n+(2^(i-1)+2^i*n+(2^i*n)^2+2^(i+1)*n` and the it's pretty straight forward to get the complexity: `O(4^m*n^2)`